# Microsoft Azure Speech Service - Can I use a USB headset instead of an a recommended microphone array in conversation transcription in real-time mode

Tags: speech-to-text

I am trying to use ConversationTranscriber.StartTranscribingAsync() API. in realtime transcription mode using my USB headset. I am not sure how to supply the microphone information. I have tried AudioConfig.FromDefaultSpeakerOutput() as well as AudioConfig.FromMicrophoneInput(). Out of trials, sometimes program exits with access violation. Other times, I have also seen error "SPXERR_RUNTIME_ERROR" with various combination of supplied microphone configuration.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.